# NextJS Warning when adding NextUI theme

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, next.js, nextui

I'm using latest NextJS. I already used next-theme for adding dark mode switcher function. But after using a Button from NextUI, I getting this Warning.

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-theme,style
html
RedirectErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9
RedirectBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:24
NotFoundErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9
NotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:62
DevRootNotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:24
ReactDevOverlay@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9
HotReload@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:294:37
Router@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:157:93
ErrorBoundaryHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:82:9
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:110:53
AppRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:440:47
ServerRoot@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:126:24
RSCComponent
Root@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:142:24
```

Comment: Sir, Please edit the above question & add your code in which you are importing Button from NextUI, & code for layout.js, & also dark mode switcher function that you wrote etc. & any other code (which may be required)
It will help in finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add suppressHydrationWarning to your html element in your root layout

Comment: Hello, Thanks...Already tried. But it is not the permanent solution.